# How do I use kml data queried from a google fusion table that is returned in a jsonp object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, jsonp, google-fusion-tables

I am querying a google fusion table for a list of polygons, which are in the table as kml polygons. The query returns a jsonp object containing what looks like coordinate data. What I need to do is retrieve those coordinates from the jsonp object and put them in an array of google api polygons so I can draw them each with their own color on a google map. I am performing this query using the jquery $.ajax() function. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a generic parser for the JSONP object that is returned by the query, hopefully it will point you in the right direction:

Generic GeoJSON parsing for Fusion Tables v1.0 API examples:

- [Polylines](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=39.923549&lng=-86.306907&zoom=10&type=m&tableid=1im8RszWUjZZhZdBnO8C0rfWGvT059O2EKk6TvZs&tablequery=SELECT%20%20geometry,%20GRID_CODE%20FROM)
- [Polygons](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=37.174668&lng=-38.845970&zoom=2&type=m&tableid=1foc3xO9DyfSIF6ofvN0kp2bxSfSeKog5FbdWdQ&tablequery=SELECT%20%20kml_4326%,%name%20FROM&where=name%20does%20not%20contain%20%27Antarctica%27)
- [Markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=14.620282&lng=-90.504716&zoom=12&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20%20geometry,%20name,%20description%20FROM&tableid=1npi-QWwoZ6LP_9wwHiwiG2omzMm6R9Qoj5aMjkM)